# WP Undeletable column in Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

there is something strange happening on my site. I have in Posts section column called `post_views` which isn't created by any plugin and it is also undeletable. I've tried searching column name in database and no results found. I've also tried disabling plugins and themes one by one and it's still there.

[image: Column post_views in Posts section]

I've also tried unset it with `manage_posts_columns` hook and it didn't work.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', array($this, 'remove_columns'));     
function remove_columns($columns) {
    unset( $columns['post_views'] );
    return $columns;
}
```

Then i tried to `var_dump($columns)` and found out, that there's no column called `post_views`. I've also used third party plugin like Admin Columns to get rid off it, but that also doesn't work. And then I tried to re-install Wordpress in hopes of getting restored values and that didn't work either. I'm out of ideas...

Could someone please tell me where are column values stored and how can I get rid of `post_views`? Thanks!

Comment: Have to tried deactivating all plugins and setting the theme to the twentytwenty wordpress theme at the same time?

Comment: Yes, and it's still there. I don't udnerstand it at all... But thanks for reply.

Comment: Using a completly fresh database and wordpress install will solve this problem. If it still occurs, you are not using an empty database and fresh wordpress install. I don't think there can be something saved by your browser like in the local storage that will cause this. You have tried incognito browser window and other browser? Would be strange but worth a try if it occurs on a new wordpress page with no modifications so far.

Comment: Well, as you can see, I have there too many posts which I can't loose, so clean reinstall with fresh database isn't unfortunately option for me. :( But thanks anyway.

Comment: But you can export your whole posts under tools wp-export and import them to the new site. You can keep the old site while you fill the new site. Maybe this plugin can also help https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ or just google duplicate wordpress site

Comment: Thank you so much, this will help me a lot! :)